# How do I delete a Tkinter label using a button command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.7

I want my program to run in a way that once the user presses the <kbd>Info</kbd> button, a label called `GameInfoLabel` is displayed due to a command from the <kbd>Info</kbd> button. Within the same condition (if the <kbd>Info</kbd> button is pressed), I want to add a <kbd>Back</kbd> button that deletes/destroys the `GameInfoLabel`.

I have attempted to implement this in the code below, but I'm getting the message

> NameError: name 'GameInfoLabel' is not defined.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
root.title("Game Menu") 
root.geometry("1920x1080")  
root.resizable(True, True) 

def QuitGameInfo():
    GameInfoLabel.destroy()
    BackInfoButton['state'] = NORMAL


def GameInfo(): 
    RulesNotepad = open("GameInfo.txt",'r')
    Rules = RulesNotepad.read()
    GameInfoLabel = Label(root, text = Rules, fg = "blue", bg = "red", height = "14", width = "140").pack()
    BackInfoButton = Button(root, text = "Back", command = QuitGameInfo).pack() 
    RulesNotepad.close()

button3 = Button(root, text = "Info", command = GameInfo, width = "20", height = "3").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are few issues in your code: 1) `GameInfoLabel` is a local variable inside `GameInfo()` so it cannot be accessed inside `QuitGameInfo()`.  That causes the error; 2) `GameInfoLabel` is `None` because it is result of `Label(...).pack()`; 3) `GameInfoButton` inside `QuitGameInfo()` is not defined.

Comment: Why do you change `BackInfoButton['state']` to `NORMAL` as it is already in `NORMAL` state?

Comment: I have no idea why I even included that line looking back at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to that `GameInfoLabel` is a local variable inside `GameInfo()` and it is not accessible inside `QuitGameInfo()`.

You can fix this error by either declaring `GameInfoLabel` as global or pass it to `QuitGameInfo()` via argument.  Same apply on `BackInfoButton` as well.

However you need to fix another issue: both `GameInfoLabel` and `BackInfoButton` are `None` because they are result of `pack()`.

Below is the modified code using global solution:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
root.title("Game Menu") 
root.geometry("1920x1080")  
root.resizable(True, True) 

def QuitGameInfo():
    GameInfoLabel.destroy()
    #BackInfoButton['state'] = NORMAL   # why ??? Should it be destroyed as well?
    BackInfoButton.destroy()


def GameInfo():
    global GameInfoLabel, BackInfoButton 
    with open("GameInfo.txt",'r') as RulesNotepad:
        Rules = RulesNotepad.read()
    GameInfoLabel = Label(root, text = Rules, fg = "blue", bg = "red", height = "14", width = "140")
    GameInfoLabel.pack()
    BackInfoButton = Button(root, text = "Back", command = QuitGameInfo)
    BackInfoButton.pack() 

Button(root, text = "Info", command = GameInfo, width = "20", height = "3").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

However I would suggest to use a frame to hold the `GameInfoLabel` and `BackInfoButton` and the frame is hidden initially.  When <kbd>Info</kbd> button is clicked, show the frame.  When <kbd>Back</kbd> button is clicked, hide the frame.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
root.title("Game Menu") 
root.geometry("1920x1080")  
root.resizable(True, True) 

def GameInfo():
    with open("GameInfo.txt",'r') as RulesNotepad:
        Rules = RulesNotepad.read()
    GameInfoLabel.config(text=Rules)
    info_frame.pack()  # show the game info frame

Button(root, text="Info", command=GameInfo, width="20", height="3").pack()

# create the game info frame but don't show it initially
info_frame = Frame(root)
GameInfoLabel = Label(info_frame, fg="blue", bg="red", height="14", width="140")
GameInfoLabel.pack()
Button(info_frame, text="Back", command=info_frame.pack_forget).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in acw1668's comment `GameInfoLabel` is local to the `GameInfo()` method. This means once this method has finished running anything declared in it ceases to exist.

The usual solution to this is passing/returning variables to functions to get results for instance your game info could return the label, however since you want to call these functions automatically when an event occurs, e.g. your button is pressed, this is not so easy.

I believe the easiest solution to your problem would be to declare the `GameInfoLabel` variable globally (in the global scope), this is not always the best coding practice but I'm not certain of tkinter's ability to pass variables parameters to an event handler and this can be complicated.

Also as mentioned by acw1668 you call .pack() immediately on the new label which is returned from the initialization `Label(...)`. Pack then does not return the label so we do that separately.

This should work, give it a careful read.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
root.title("Game Menu") 
root.geometry("1920x1080")  
root.resizable(True, True) 

# Declare any global UI Components
GameInfoLabel = None # Dont set a Label yet

def QuitGameInfo():
    GameInfoLabel.destroy()
    BackInfoButton['state'] = NORMAL

def GameInfo(): 
    RulesNotepad = open("GameInfo.txt",'r')
    Rules = RulesNotepad.read()
    GameInfoLabel = Label(root, text = Rules, fg = "blue", bg = "red", height = "14", width = "140")
    GameInfoLabel.pack()

    BackInfoButton = Button(root, text = "Back", command = QuitGameInfo).pack() 
    RulesNotepad.close()

button3 = Button(root, text = "Info", command = GameInfo, width = "20", height = "3")
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```